# Unable to edit transactional emails on Magento Community v1.8.1

Tags: magento, email

I am running Magento Community v1.8.1.

There are no entries in the drop down bar at `Admin > System > Transactional Emails`. Under `sales emails`, I see the `default emails from Locale` selected but I can't seem to edit these default emails.

How can I make the admin panel's drop down bar start showing these `default emails` ? Must I go into the PHP on my hosting site to edit anything to make this happen, else what should I do?
Greatly appreciate any help I can get on this!

Answer (score 0):

You can have two kinds of transactional email templates: based on file ex. `app/locale/en_US/template/email` and based on database `Admin \ System \ Transactional Emails`.

If you read `Default template from Locale` it means that the files in `app/locale/en_US/template` folder are used.

If you want to create a Database template, you can copy the file content and paste it into a new Template `in Admin \ System \ Transactional emails`.

Comment: Hi Enzo! Thanks for the answer! Right now, I can't Add New Template at all under Admin \ System \ Transactional Emails, nothing under the drop down bar. As such, no default templates to load. Do you know if this is some kind of bug, or do I have to access the app/locale/en_US/template/email such that I can force them to show in the drop down bar? Btw, the app/locale --> that's PHP is it?

Comment: Can you check in your logs (ex. var/log/system.log) if any error is present?
Probably an installed extension is causing this error.

Comment: Just enabled the log settings under System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings. Can see a system.log and an exception.log (file names) there. Really sorry about this, but rather new to Magento, but how can I check the logs for errors? Can it be from Magento backend or must I go into the hosting site backend?

Comment: I would do in this way: first read the system.log and exception.log and check if there is written something that allows you to identify the problem (the name of an installed extension, for example); second, try to disable the installed extensions and see if the problem persists. 
Else you can post an abstract of the system.log file.

Comment: Thanks Enzo. Can't seem to locate the problem, and the system.log file's pretty huge - full of text. Also went to contact my theme's support team, and they mentioned this: 

You can edit the e-mails manually from here:

/app/locale/en_US/template/email/

Is it fine if I edit the templates through this link, say perhaps through the file manager on cPanel?

Comment: I would delete the system.log file, in order to let the system to recreate one, containing (hopefully) the errors occurring.
Of course you can edit directly the files, but I would solve the problem you have on your installation. :)